# Basic Authentication with PHP gives an endless loop

Tags: php, authentication, basic-authentication

For some reason I can't get Basic Authentication to work using PHP on my server. I am using the exact code from the manual page:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
?>
```

However, when I run it, I can never get beyond the prompt.

If I put this same code on my other server, it works fine.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Both servers are WAMP stacks and Apache has the auth_basic_module enabled. The PHP.ini files are practically identical as well.

I glanced at the headers and after I enter my username/password, there is the "Authorization: Basic XXXXXX" header being sent.

Comment: try a `diff` on the two `php.ini` files, just in case you are missing something. You could also compare the apache confs too.

Comment: Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the used PHP interface. The environment variable `PHP_AUTH_USER` is only used for mod_php and if Apache helped.

If you initialize the authorization from the script, then you have to look for the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header, and decode and split it up yourself. Look at this comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#94349

For FastCGI setups or suexec invokations you might not even have that header present in the environment variables. It's filtered out as security precaution. The common workaround is to rewrite the header using a .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Thus it becomes available with mixed-case as `$_SERVER["HTTP_Authorization"]`.

Comment: I'm marking your response as the answer because it was extremely helpful. I don't know why (perhaps you do), but the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION environment variable was being renamed to REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION. I can check for that, rename it to HTTP_AUTHORIZATION and then continue with the code as directed in the php manual comment you posted.

Comment: @Brandon0: The `REDIRECT_` prefix is another peculiarity of the FastCGI variant of PHP. But I never found out in which circumstance it does that and which configuration settings trigger it.

Comment: @Brandon0 I'm having the same problem but I couldn't really understand what is the fix you've implemented in order to solve it. Can you share the changes you've made in the code?

Comment: @mario : same for you. What is the changes in the code need to be made in order to solve this issue?

Comment: @DMEM Like OP said, he looked for the `REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header instead.

Comment: @mario : Thank you for the answer. What solved it for me eventually was your solution with adding the rule to the .htaccess file. Thanks.