# Problem: Password Protecting Particular PHP5 Page

Tags: php, authentication, password-protection

Dear folks,
There seems to be a problem with password protection for accessing a particular php page:
@ When I embed this test code, I am presented nicely with a popup authentification dialog.
@ If I fill in the fields and press enter, it does not show the password/login on the page!
@ It just presents me again the auth dialog with emptied fields... again and again
@ After 3 tries orso it sais unauthorised to access...

What could be going on? Thanks very much for your suggestions!

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
     header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
     header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
     echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
     exit;
} else {
     echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
     echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

Ive Apache 2.0x Fedora with PHP 5.2.3 and nowhere else is password set in apache htacces or anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PHP_AUTH_USER` is available for mod_php setups at best. For CGI or FastCGI setups you will have to manually unmarshall the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header. To make matters worse, it is often not present for security reasons. ( [Basic Authentication with PHP gives an endless loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928228/basic-authentication-with-php-gives-an-endless-loop/4928317#4928317) )

You will have to check with phpinfo() which variant you can use. Then apply one of the more complex examples from the comments in http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#94349